# google saml setup and configuration with omniauth-saml in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, saml, google-apps, saml-2.0

I am trying to create Google SAML SSO custom app integration for my Rails website. I am using omniauth-saml gem.

However, I am really confused with "ACS URL" and "Entity ID" that needs to be set under "Service Provider Details" during google saml idp setup.

I have a few questions:

1. What should be the ACS URL?

My understanding: It should be the URL at which the SAML assertion should be received sent by Google. If that is correct, what is the use of :assertion_consumer_service_url, which can be set in rails app as:
    `Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :saml,
        :assertion_consumer_service_url => "acs url here!!" # http://www.my-rails-app.com/sso/saml_asertion_handler
      ...
    end`

Will this overwrite the ACS URL set in the google portal and send response to the one specified in the Omniauth config?

2. What should be the Entity ID?

My understanding: It should be the url of my rails app(http://www.my-rails-app.com). However, I found a few places where saml metadata url is specified(http://my-rails-app.com/auth/saml/metadata).

3. What should be the issuer in OmniAuth::Builder in rails config?
   My understanding: Just like Entity Id, I found it be the 'application name'(http://www.my-rails-app.com) as well as the path to the metadata (http://my-rails-app.com/auth/saml/metadata).

I am very new to this and any guidance is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. The google **ACS URL** is the callback url into your rails app. This is where Google, in your case, sends the SAML response. The default for this is `http://example.com/auth/saml/callback`.
2. & 3. The google **Entity Id** should match exactly the `:issuer` SAML config property in your rails app. Most people use their domain name for this to reduce the chance of a naming conflict.

Answer (score 0):

ACS is the Assertion Consumer Service URL. It is the destination on the Service Provider (SP) where the SAML Assertion is sent. You have to tell Google as the IDP where to send the assertion. And you have to define the ACS on your SP in Rails. Your entity ID is a unique identifier for your app, usually set to your base domain URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rostam for responding. so if I set ACS as my-rails-app.com in google saml app and define staging.my-rails-app.com as ACS in my rails app. Will I be getting assertion on staging.my-rails-app.com?

I actually want to know if I have 2 servers, production and staging and I need to test the same SAML app authentication on both servers, can I define respective ACS in the respective rails apps and does it get more precedence over the default ACS defined with google?

please excuse me. I am very new to this.